# Ansible: Not able to get value from nested list

Tags: python, list, ansible, jinja2

I need help querying a nested list output from the `ansible.builtin.uri` module so that I can use it in the future.

Here are my tasks:

```
vars:
  __USER_LOGINS:
    - johndoe
    - janedoe

- name: FETCH | IPA | Getting HPC user information
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: "https://ipa.example.com/ipa/json" 
    method: POST
    ca_path: ipa.ca.cert
    body: |
      {
        "method": "user_find",
        "params": [
          [
            "{{ item | default('') }}"
          ],
          {
            "all": "true",
            "version": "2.248"
          }
        ],
        "id": 0
      }
    body_format: json
    validate_certs: false
    use_gssapi: true
    url_username: admin
    url_password: password
    timeout: 180 
    headers:
      referer: "https://ipa.example.com/ipa"
      Content-Type: "application/json"
      Accept: "applicaton/json; charset=UTF-8"
  loop:
    "{{ __USER_LOGINS }}"
  register: __user_find
```

And a debug of __user_find.results prints the output:

```
ok: [ipa.example.com] => 
  __user_find.results:
  - ansible_loop_var: item
    item: johndoe
    json:
      result:
        result:
        - cn:
          - John Doe
          displayname:
          - John Doe
          dn: uid=johndoe,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com
          gecos:
          - John Doe
          gidnumber:
          - '1237800290'
          givenname:
          - John
          homedirectory:
          - home/johndoe
          initials:
          - JD
          krbprincipalname:
          - johndoe@EXAMPLE.COM
          loginshell:
          - /bin/bash
          mail:
          - johndoe@example.com
          - johndoe@external.com
          memberof_group:
          - ipausers
          - other-group01
          - other-group02
          mepmanagedentry:
          - cn=johndoe,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com
          nsaccountlock: false
          objectclass:
          - top
          - person
          - organizationalperson
          - inetorgperson
          - inetuser
          - posixaccount
          - krbprincipalaux
          - krbticketpolicyaux
          - ipaobject
          - ipasshuser
          - ipaSshGroupOfPubKeys
          - mepOriginEntry
          - ipantuserattrs
          preserved: false
          sn:
          - Doe
          uid:
          - johndoe
          uidnumber:
          - '1234567890'
  - ansible_loop_var: item
    item: janedoe
    json:
      result:
        result:
        - cn:
          - Jane Doe
          displayname:
          - Jane Doe
          dn: uid=janedoe,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com
          gecos:
          - Jane Doe
          gidnumber:
          - '1237800291'
          givenname:
          - Jane
          homedirectory:
          - home/janedoe
          initials:
          - JD
          krbprincipalname:
          - janedoe@EXAMPLE.COM
          loginshell:
          - /bin/bash
          mail:
          - janedoe@example.com
          - janedoe@external.com
          memberof_group:
          - ipausers
          - other-group01
          - other-group02
          mepmanagedentry:
          - cn=janedoe,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com
          nsaccountlock: false
          objectclass:
          - top
          - person
          - organizationalperson
          - inetorgperson
          - inetuser
          - posixaccount
          - krbprincipalaux
          - krbticketpolicyaux
          - ipaobject
          - ipasshuser
          - ipaSshGroupOfPubKeys
          - mepOriginEntry
          - ipantuserattrs
          preserved: false
          sn:
          - Doe
          uid:
          - janedoe
          uidnumber:
          - '1234567891'
```

I am able to run the tasks below to fetch values for each item, except for the `memberof_group` value.

```
- name: Get User's first name
  debug:
    msg: |
      {% for item in __user_find['results'] | community.general.json_query('[*].json.result.result') %}
      {{ item[0].mail }}
      {% endfor %}
```

```
TASK [task01 : debug] *********************************************************
Wednesday 14 June 2023  10:23:50 -0400 (0:00:00.851)       0:00:05.633 ******** 
ok: [ipa.example.com] => 
  msg: |-
    ['johndoe@example.com', 'johndoe@external.com']
    ['janedoe@example.com', 'janedoe@external.com']
```

When I run:

```
- name: Get User's first name
  debug:
    msg: |
      {% for item in __user_find['results'] | community.general.json_query('[*].json.result.result') %}
      {{ item[0].memberof_group }}
      {% endfor %}
```

I should get the output:

```
TASK [task01 : debug] *********************************************************
Wednesday 14 June 2023  10:23:50 -0400 (0:00:00.851)       0:00:05.633 ******** 
ok: [ipa.example.com] => 
  msg: |-
    ['ipausers', 'other-group01', 'other-group02']
    ['ipausers', 'other-group01', 'other-group02']
```

Instead, I get the output:

```
fatal: [ipa.example.com]: FAILED! => 
  msg: |-
    The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'memberof_group'
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary from the results

```yaml
  user_find_dict: "{{ dict(user_find.results|
                           json_query('[].[item, json.result.result[0]]')) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  user_find_dict:
    janedoe:
      cn: [Jane Doe]
      displayname: [Jane Doe]
      dn: uid=janedoe,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com
      gecos: [Jane Doe]
      gidnumber: ['1237800291']
      givenname: [Jane]
      homedirectory: [home/janedoe]
      initials: [JD]
      krbprincipalname: [janedoe@EXAMPLE.COM]
      loginshell: [/bin/bash]
      mail: [janedoe@example.com, janedoe@external.com]
      memberof_group: [ipausers, other-group01, other-group02]
      mepmanagedentry: ['cn=janedoe,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com']
      nsaccountlock: false
      objectclass: [top, person, organizationalperson, inetorgperson, inetuser, posixaccount,
        krbprincipalaux, krbticketpolicyaux, ipaobject, ipasshuser, ipaSshGroupOfPubKeys,
        mepOriginEntry, ipantuserattrs]
      preserved: false
      sn: [Doe]
      uid: [janedoe]
      uidnumber: ['1234567891']
    johndoe:
      cn: [John Doe]
      displayname: [John Doe]
      dn: uid=johndoe,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com
      gecos: [John Doe]
      gidnumber: ['1237800290']
      givenname: [John]
      homedirectory: [home/johndoe]
      initials: [JD]
      krbprincipalname: [johndoe@EXAMPLE.COM]
      loginshell: [/bin/bash]
      mail: [johndoe@example.com, johndoe@external.com]
      memberof_group: [ipausers, other-group01, other-group02]
      mepmanagedentry: ['cn=johndoe,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com']
      nsaccountlock: false
      objectclass: [top, person, organizationalperson, inetorgperson, inetuser, posixaccount,
        krbprincipalaux, krbticketpolicyaux, ipaobject, ipasshuser, ipaSshGroupOfPubKeys,
        mepOriginEntry, ipantuserattrs]
      preserved: false
      sn: [Doe]
      uid: [johndoe]
      uidnumber: ['1234567890']
```

---

Get the attribute *memberof_group* either by *json_query*

```yaml
  memberof_group: "{{ user_find_dict|
                      json_query('*.memberof_group') }}"
```

, or by *map*

```yaml
  memberof_group: "{{ user_find_dict|
                      dict2items|
                      map(attribute='value.memberof_group') }}"
```

Both options give the same result

```yaml
  memberof_group:
    - [ipausers, other-group01, other-group02]
    - [ipausers, other-group01, other-group02]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    user_find:
      results:
        - ansible_loop_var: item
          item: johndoe
          json:
            result:
              result:
              - cn: [John Doe]
                displayname: [John Doe]
                dn: uid=johndoe,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com
                gecos: [John Doe]
                gidnumber: ['1237800290']
                givenname: [John]
                homedirectory: [home/johndoe]
                initials: [JD]
                krbprincipalname: [johndoe@EXAMPLE.COM]
                loginshell: [/bin/bash]
                mail: [johndoe@example.com, johndoe@external.com]
                memberof_group: [ipausers, other-group01, other-group02]
                mepmanagedentry: ['cn=johndoe,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com']
                nsaccountlock: false
                objectclass: [top, person, organizationalperson, inetorgperson, inetuser,
                  posixaccount, krbprincipalaux, krbticketpolicyaux, ipaobject, ipasshuser,
                  ipaSshGroupOfPubKeys, mepOriginEntry, ipantuserattrs]
                preserved: false
                sn: [Doe]
                uid: [johndoe]
                uidnumber: ['1234567890']
        - ansible_loop_var: item
          item: janedoe
          json:
            result:
              result:
              - cn: [Jane Doe]
                displayname: [Jane Doe]
                dn: uid=janedoe,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com
                gecos: [Jane Doe]
                gidnumber: ['1237800291']
                givenname: [Jane]
                homedirectory: [home/janedoe]
                initials: [JD]
                krbprincipalname: [janedoe@EXAMPLE.COM]
                loginshell: [/bin/bash]
                mail: [janedoe@example.com, janedoe@external.com]
                memberof_group: [ipausers, other-group01, other-group02]
                mepmanagedentry: ['cn=janedoe,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com']
                nsaccountlock: false
                objectclass: [top, person, organizationalperson, inetorgperson, inetuser,
                  posixaccount, krbprincipalaux, krbticketpolicyaux, ipaobject, ipasshuser,
                  ipaSshGroupOfPubKeys, mepOriginEntry, ipantuserattrs]
                preserved: false
                sn: [Doe]
                uid: [janedoe]
                uidnumber: ['1234567891']


    user_find_dict: "{{ dict(user_find.results|
                             json_query('[].[item, json.result.result[0]]')) }}"
    memberof_group1: "{{ user_find_dict|
                         json_query('*.memberof_group') }}"
    memberof_group2: "{{ user_find_dict|
                         dict2items|
                         map(attribute='value.memberof_group') }}"

  tasks:
    
    - debug:
        var: user_find_dict|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: memberof_group1|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: memberof_group2|to_yaml
```

Comment: This works for creating a dictionary from the list, but I'm not able to search for a string in `memberof_group1` in Jinja2 using

`- debug:`
       `msg: |`
           `{% for item in user_find_dict if ('other-group02' in memberof_group1) %}`
           `{{ user_find_dict[item].displayname }}`
           `{% endfor %}`